# Is it possible to pause php script and then change execution time then continue?

Tags: php, time, execution

I had question to find combination of sets of some problem, and made program, just I needed from me to wait while computer solves. But I didn't know that it will need days to solve.

I started php script, which I set time to 10 hours, but my problem didn't solve yet and needs about 40 hours more, is it possible to change time of execution without stopping script. Because don't want to wait 9 hours which waited before. Please help me.

Comment: I don't know about that case but perhaps it's enough if you can restart/shut down & start up the server (if on localhost, for example). Then the PHP script is terminated and you can change execution time.

Comment: I know about it, about I don't want to terminate it

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Unix system? If yes, try `Ctrl+Z` to suspend it and then `fg` or `bg` to continue. More details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/476873/what-is-effect-of-ctrl-z-on-a-unix-linux-application).

Comment: no, I use windows, actually its finished, I restarted with removing limit